# How to Automate Rsync for a Local Backup?

Tags: backup, cron, rsync

I would like to back up the /home folder located on my SSD drive to a partition I've made on a local HDD every week using rsync.

I've successfully used the rsync command to do a one-off backup, but I can't seem to automate the command correctly.

Here's what I've entered into my crontab...

```
10 1200 * * 5 rsync -av --delete /home /media/directory here
```

What am I not doing right? Thank you!

Comment: About a script: Have a look at https://opensource.com/article/17/1/rsync-backup-linux (and then https://github.com/opensourceway/rsync-backup-script)

Answer (score 3):

Crontab entry #2 = hours.

> Entry: Hour when the process will be started [0-23]

1200 is not valid

10 minutes past 12 midday every friday would be either of ...

```
10 12 * * 5
10 12 * * Fri
```

Comment: Changed it to this: 44 12 * * 5 rsync -av --delete /home /directory/   How do I check if it's working?

Comment: That would be 12:44 PM on fridays. Easiest to see if it is working: Put the command into a script and add logging. By the way: the "v" is "verbose" meaning echo results.  If so add `>/tmp/rsync.txt` to have it send the output to /tmp/rsync.txt

Comment: how would i add that to a script? haven't made a script before.

Comment: ehm that is a bit too much for comments ;) google it though; lots of examples out there